# Bing maps pushpins hide when we navigate back from another view

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I have created a map view using Bing map in my winrt application.When i navigate back from another view and click on pushpin for display an expanded pushpin. For this i add a UserControl to as a child of Map, that time all another pushpins are disappear.What is the reason? Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

I suspect somewhere in your code you are clearing the children of the map and that's why they are disappearing. Adding a custom UserControl to the map works fine and I do it all the time ad have only come across your issue when I accidentally had code that cleared the children of the map. Note that is a dedicated Bing Maps forum for the Windows 8 controls where you will get answered a lot faster in the future here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=bingmapswindows8